# Binding Shape Keys to a Empty with Distance Influence

Tags: shape-keys

Is it possible to bind shape keys to a empty and depending of the angle and distance it has influence on a character or object?

Example:
https://youtu.be/zM3psSxWTYM?t=39

Basically exactly the same, I timestamped the video at 39 seconds

Here's a .blend file of what I got so far:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnxeMsAWKW1ci1YaB1CoPcZJmphi

Comment: You can use drivers to do it.

Comment: I looked into drivers but I'm a freshman with blender and I can't seem to make it work. This is what I have so far: https://imgur.com/a/UFO88VM

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work but my issues is that the shape key gets applied equally to the body. For example I'm coming from the right side but the character changes equally on the right and left side. I would like to have it independent. Currently it just increases or decreases the total value of the whole shape key.

Comment: could you have some more details editing your answer or providing some picture (hard to figure out exactly what you mean)

Comment: Sorry for the bad quality, but I think it's good enough: https://gph.is/g/EqNBx35 as you can see the shape key gets applied equally. I want it to have influence on vertices depending from which side I'm coming like in the video above.

Comment: To tell the truth I see nearly nothing on the animation. But think I catch the point: you may either have one empty by shape key or use a different axis of the empty for each shape key.

Comment: Mmmh, I was hoping to have all in one like on the example video above, where the sphere applies a shape key to vertices in range instead of the whole body.

Comment: If the shapekey includes both head and body morphing, I think that's not possible

Comment: Technically yes but in this case I just used the vertices group of the upper abdomen. What would I have to do if I just use a shape key for the head for example?

Comment: Oh ok good. so that should work. If not should find a way to show the setting either adding images in the question or uploading the blend file.

Comment: I'll prepare something new since I can't share the model in my example gif.

Comment: I added a .blend file to my original question.

Comment: ok, get it. But what is not working here?

Comment: The controller only influences the strength of the shape key globally, but I want it to have only influence on vertices in range like in the making of video I posted.

Comment: Is it due to "var + 1" which should be var? Or by range do you mean keep only an interval inside [0,1]?

Comment: I don't think what I want is able to work with my current setup. Like I said, I basically just have a controller of the global shape key so far. Depending on how close I get to the character the shape key gets applied on the WHOLE character from a 0 to max value. I don't want that though, I want a spherical influence area which has impact on vertices in range. I don't know how to phrase it differently. All I can say is that I want exactly the same like the wolfman making of video timestamped at 39 seconds. ^^

Comment: What I need is basically something which has influence in a spherical area, which applies a shape key to vertices in it but smoothed. Let's say vertices in the middle of the sphere have a shape key value of max. and vertices with more distance to the core have less influence till they reach a value of 0 at the border of the sphere. I hope this clarifies better what I want.

Comment: oh ok... simply use the distance in the driver parameters. Use another empty and place it at the center of the head. Then set distance in the driver between this last empty and the controller. You'll have a 'var' and if want to have more amplitude just set var/3 (say) in the expression. Need I write something about that in answer part?

Comment: I tried this, but it still seems to apply the shape key on the whole face equally: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnxeMsAWKW1ci1eEYb4LQkVM7L5d
If I move the second sphere fast on the x-axis left and right it's pretty obvious that this is the case.

Comment: The face movement are very small on this shape key. But no, I don't see what you say: that seems progressive as the controller moves.

Comment: The whole face at once is progressive yes. But not from left to right and vice versa. If I want for example half the face only morphed it still seems not to work.

Comment: I get the point (at last) but failed to find a solution. Have played around 'vertex weight influence' modifier but was not able to make it work

Comment: Thanks for trying though, I will ask more around and try to solve it myself simultanously. I can imagine it comes down to scripting.

Comment: If you find something, please ping me (the subject is interesting)